# How to turn on the flash led continuously using FLASH_MODE_ON?

Tags: android, camera, led

I searched on the web to turn on the flash using this mode but no solution work so far... I want to use this mode because some devices doesn't support the FLASH_MODE_TORCH, so I want to force the focus or another thing to turn on the flash continuously. I tried to restart the "autofocus" when the flash turns off automatically but it takes too much time (the period between two "flashing" is quite long).

So I ask you if you know some way to do it, thanks ! :)

Actually I use :

```
public static Camera Cam;
public static Parameters CamParams;

    Cam = Camera.open();
    CamParams = Cam.getParameters();

    CamParams.setFlashMod(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    Cam.setParameters(CamParams);
    Cam.startPreview();
    Cam.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() 
    {
       public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) 
       {}
    });
```